# html5 video tag unwanted border

Tags: html, css

I oddly have an unwanted purple border when clicking the play button on a html5 video that has native controls.  How do I remove this border?

```
<div id="missionVideo" style="text-align: center;">
  <video playsinline controls poster="posterurlhere">
    <source src="videourlhere" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

[image: Video with Border]

Comment: Have you tried to add `border: none`?

Comment: Yes - i've tried border: none and border: 0px;, on the div and on the video tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be the `outline` that appears on selection. To full proof, remove `outline` and `border`.

```
video {
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}
```